# Is open() on linux with O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL atomic if the file is on a samba share from a Win10 PC?

Tags: c++, linux, samba

I'm porting some code from Win32 to Linux that is using lock files.
I did an implementation with `open` for Linux, but I'm just not sure if it is going to work if the file is on a Samba share. I tried it and it seams to work, but I'm not sure how reliable it is.

I'm using linux `open()` with `O_CREAT | O_EXCL` for that, so that it succeeds only by creating the file if it does not already exist.
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html

Is the following function call going to be atomic if multiple computers running my software are trying to create the lock file at the same time? I don't care who gets it, as long as only one gets the lock and all the others don't. For those who don't get the lock I expect `open` to return -1.

```
m_iFileDescriptor = open(m_sPath.c_str(), O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0666);
```

Comment: What is meaning of word *atomic* in here? Automatic?

Comment: @0x476f72616e, "atomic" means as if a single instruction, all at once, without an observable intermediate state between the start of the call and its return.  That's not actually quite the right term for what the OP means -- it would be sufficient, but it is not necessary -- yet the rest of that paragraph clarifies sufficiently.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are on safe ground here.  I took a quick look at the [SMB protocol documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-cifs/f2a0f032-7545-41c9-9ceb-aab39852c11a0) and there is a `FILE_CREATE` flag which does this:

> If the file already exists, the operation MUST fail. If the file does not already exist, it SHOULD be created.

which of course is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the following function call going to be atomic if multiple
>   computers running my software are trying to create the lock file at
>   the same time? I don't care who gets it, as long as only one gets the
>   lock and all the others don't. For those who don't get the lock I
>   expect `open` to return -1.

To the best of my knowledge, the facts that the file resides on a Samba share and that multiple different machines are trying to access it do not interfere with `open()` behaving as specified on every machine involved.  In particular, if no process is trying to create or remove the file other than those executing the `open()` call you presented, then at most one of those calls will succeed, returning a file descriptor, and all others will fail, returning -1.  Do note, however, that it is possible for *all* of them to fail.

In the event of failure, you need to check the value of `errno` to determine the reason; it will take the value `EEXIST` if the failure results from the file already existing, but it may take a wide variety of other values, too.  These are described, among other places, in the manual page linked in the question.

Comment: Thanks! Hope other people will confirm that. Our code can receive a timeout/duration as an argument, so we can retry if it fails. So the only issue for us is to make sure that only one machine get the lock.